# How to send data from python client to Django web server?

Tags: python, json, django

I'd like python3 program to send JSON data to Django web server and print them on web page. This is what I have in Views.py:

```
def receive_json(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        received_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        return StreamingHttpResponse('it was post request: ' + str(received_data))
    return StreamingHttpResponse('it was get request')
```

And the python code:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
data = {"data": [{'key1':'val1'}, {'key2':'val2'}]}
headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
r.text
```

However, it shows this message:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /
[28/May/2021 16:51:31] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 2864
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
data = {"data": [{'key1':'val1'}, {'key2':'val2'}]}
headers = {'content-type':'application/json','Cookie':'csrftoken=axXsa39e5hq8gqlTjJFHAbUWtg2FQgnSd3cxxkx9khatqgersthtSryDxtF0cVCk'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
r.text
```

i think these may works by adding Cookie but it would be better if u use @csrf_exempt decorater in receive_json function by these way

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def receive_json(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        received_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        return StreamingHttpResponse('it was post request: ' + str(received_data))
    return StreamingHttpResponse('it was get request')
```

Comment: Thanks but now it shows: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /

Comment: Yes u have to use your own CSRF token or use csrf_exempt decorater its the only way

Comment: Okay, I'm new to django and I'm little confused if I have to type also something into index.html...

Comment: yes {% csrf_token %} inside your form tag just use these no need to write own token these will add automatic an token to your request

Comment: Using `@csrf_exempt` is not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing. It's the equivalent of not understanding how to use a key and working around it by leaving your door unlocked.

Comment: @Harsh Parekh I tried it and now I got: name 'StreamingHttpResponse' is not defined

Comment: Okay, so just changing StreamingHttpResponse to HttpResponse solved it :D

Comment: So now it sends there the data but when I go to the page, it shows: 'it was a get request.' That's right but how do I make it print the data on webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need first to perform a GET request to get a csrftoken, than post that together with the data. There are a few ways to do this. Here is one (untested however):

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"


s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
headers = {
  'content-type':'application/json',
  'X-CSRFToken': s.cookies["csrftoken"],
}
data = {"data": [{'key1':'val1'}, {'key2':'val2'}]}
r = s.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
r.text
```

You can find more information in [Django's CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/).